# Не прекращается отладочное выполнение телеграм бота на Python в VSCode

Tags: python, telebot, visual-studio-code

Пишу своего первого бота на Python в VSCode.
Пока тестирую его запуская через интерфейс VSCode, на сервер не запускал.
Но периодически стала возникать такая ошибка:

telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 409. Description: Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running

Возникает когда останавливаю выполнение через интерфейс кнопкой стоп, а бот продолжает выполняться. Соответственно следующий раз запустить уже исправленную версию кода не дает, так как не прекращено прошлое выполнение бота. В интерфейсе VSCode отображается что ничего не выполняется, но в телеграме прошлая версия бота продолжает работать и реагировать на команды.

Конечно, можно просто ребутнуть комп, но каждый раз это делать не хочется, а ситуация повторяется периодически.
Есть какая-то команда для терминала что бы прервать работу pethon или какое-то другое решение?

Уточнение: После перезагрузки компьютера он тоже иногда сам продолжает выполняться.
Думаю один из способов решения это запросить новый токен бота у botfather, но может есть еще какое-то решение? Буду признателен.

Уточнение 2: После смены токена в botfather код с новым токеном корректно выполняется.
Но в output vscode теперь периодически вылезает ошибка, даже когда я не запускаю никакой код:
telebot.apihelper.ApiTelegramException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 401. Description: Unauthorized
так как старый процесс со старым токеном все еще пытается выполняться.
Так что вопрос по принудительному завершению процесса все еще актуален. Кроме как с моего компьютера ему выполняться неоткуда, так как бот все еще не загружен на сервер и запускался только через vscode с моего компьютера.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже нашел решение.
Добавил команду которая вызывает bot.stop_polling()